# Make numbers in array relative to 0 - 100

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I have an array of six numbers who are very close to each other:

`const numbers = [28.71, 28.53, 28.5, 28.38, 28.43, 28.44]`

I want to change the values of these numbers so that they are relative to 0 - 100.

So that the highest number is 100 and the lowest is 0 (or `n`), and the numbers in between are proportionate.

I cannot re-order these numbers.

I can normalise the array to 100 by using this:

`const maxScore = max(numbers)`

`const ratio = Math.max(...numbers) / 100;`

`const newNumbers = numbers.map((v) => (v / ratio));`

And this yields the following:

`[100, 99.37304075235109, 99.2685475444096, 98.85057471264366, 99.02473005921281, 99.05956112852664]`

However, the numbers are the same distance to each other as before.

How can I change the values of these numbers so that the lowest is 0 and the highest is 100?

Comment: You have to find both the maximum *and* the minimum.

Comment: For the input array, can you please give the expected output which follows your requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get a factor and get a normalized array.

```js
function getNormalized(values, left, right) {
    var min = Math.min(...values),
        max = Math.max(...values),
        factor = (right - left) / (max - min) ;
    return values.map(v => (v - min) * factor + left);
}

console.log(getNormalized([28.71, 28.53, 28.5, 28.38, 28.43, 28.44], 0, 100));
```

Comment: This is really clever. Thanks